# How can I use multiple Bash arguments in loop dynamically without using long regex strings?

Tags: bash

I have a directory with the following files:

- file1.jpg
- file2.jpg
- file3.jpg
- file1.png
- file2.png
- file3.png

I have a bash function named `filelist` and it looks like this:

```
filelist() {

  if [ "$1" ]
    then
      shopt -s nullglob
      for filelist in *."$@" ; do
      echo "$filelist" >> created-file-list.txt;
      done
      echo "file created listing: " $@;
    else
      filelist=`find . -type f -name "*.*" -exec basename \{} \;`
      echo "$filelist" >> created-file-list.txt
      echo "file created listing: All Files";
  fi

}
```

Goal: Be able to type as many arguments as I want for example `filelist jpg png` and create a file with a list of files of only the extensions I used as arguments. So if I type `filelist jpg` it would only show a list of files that have .jpg.

Currently: My code works great with one argument thanks to `$@`, but when I use both jpg and png it creates the following list

- file1.jpg
- file2.jpg
- file3.jpg
- png

It looks like my for loop is only running once and only using the first argument. My suspicion is I need to count how many arguments and run the loop on each one.

An obvious fix for this is to create a long regex check like `(jpg|png|jpeg|html|css)` and all of the different extensions one could ever think to type. This is not ideal because I want other people to be free to type their file extensions without breaking it if they type one that I don't have identified in my regex. Dynamic is key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your function as shown below - just loop through each extension and append the list of matching files to the output file:

```
filelist() {
  if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    shopt -s nullglob
    for ext in "$@"; do
      printf '%s\n' *."$ext" >> created-file-list.txt
      echo "created listing for extension $ext"
    done
  else
    find . -type f -name "*.*" -exec basename \{} \; >> created-file-list.txt
    echo "created listing for all files"
  fi
}
```

And you can invoke your function as:

```
filelist jpg png
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to remove all the redirections and have the caller redirect `filelist` to a file if they want to?  Then you'll obviously need to print status messages to stderr instead but that's probably a good idea regardless.

Comment: Unlike the OP's original this will overwrite, not append to, the output file(s).

Comment: There's no need for an inner loop, really.  Just `printf "%s\n" *.$ext`

Comment: @codeforester hmmm it doesn't seem to work for me. I am either getting one or the other :/ Is the double in necessary? I am getting this as my echo
file created listing for extension in
file created listing for extension jpg
file created listing for extension png

Comment: @codeforester sorry didn't see update. I'll check back in a sec

Comment: Please check now - there was a typo.

Comment: @codeforester @trippleee That did it! Thanks for your help you two.I will look further into your answer to fully understand the `printf`

Comment: To be completely correct the `"$ext"` in the loop should be in double quotes.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ -n "$1" ]
  do
    echo "Current Parameter: $1 , Remaining $#"
    #Pass $1 to some bash function or do whatever
    shift
done
```

Using the `shift` you shift the args left and get the next one by reading the `$1` variable.

See `man` bash on what shift does.

> shift [n]
>
> The positional parameters from n+1 ... are renamed to $1 ....  Parameters represented by the numbers $# down to $#-n+1 are
>   unset.  n  must
>                 be a non-negative number less than or equal to $#.  If n is 0, no parameters are changed.  If n is not given, it is assumed to
>   be 1.  If n
>                 is greater than $#, the positional parameters are not changed.  The return status is greater than zero if n is greater  than
>   $#  or  less
>                 than zero; otherwise 0.

Or you can iterate like as follows

```
for this in "$@"
 do
   echo "Param = $this";
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Sorry for my lack of understanding here. Would I then put my for loop above your echo? I am not fully understanding how to merge our two ideas together.

Comment: You might just make a function which accepts only one of the types, and then call that function within any of the above loops in this answer.